# Export two tables to Excel

Tags: html, angularjs, excel

I have 2 tables and some variables that i want to export to excel. The script ive found in the web only allows to export one table and it works.
[Script used to export to excel](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/352da2a4209691d425d4)
But i want to include the `{{month}}`,`{{location}}` and `{{year}}` and the  2 tables the `entryTable` and `exitTable` into the excel document.

This is my html

```
  <button align="right" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="exportToExcel('#entryTable')">
        <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span>
    </button>
    <h4 align="left" id="month"><b>Month:</b> {{month}} </h4>
    <h4 align="right" id="location"> <b>Local:</b> {{location}} </h4>
    <h4 align="left" id="Year"><b>year:</b> 2015</h4>
            <div class="col-lg-6" >
                <table id="entryTable" class="table table-striped">
            <tr><th colspan="4">Entry</th></tr>
             <tr>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>read ant</th>
                        <th>read act</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="result1 in Result1">
                        <td align="center">{{result1.Day}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{result1.inicial}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{result1.final}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{result1.total}}</td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <table id="exitTable" class="table table-striped">
            <tr><th colspan="4">Exit</th></tr>
             <tr>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>read ant</th>
                        <th>read act</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="result2 in Result2">
                        <td align="center">{{result2.Day}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{result2.inicial}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{result2.final}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{result2.total}}</td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>                
</div>
```

Do you have other suggestion of how to do this?

Comment: Btw, this wont work in IE9 and earlier.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Do you know other alternative?

Comment: As far as I know you simply cant do this on client side in some browsers - alternative is to generate excel on server side.